# Counting Excel Files on a File Server

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, file-management, file-sharing, windows-server

I'd like to know how many Excel files are on my File Server. There may be hundreds of thousands. When I remote into it and search for *.xls I get a huge list of files. However, when I try to right click and choose properties (for a count and total space used), nothing happens no matter how long I seem to wait.

How can I determine the count and spaced used by this file type?

Answer (score 1):

How about running `dir *.xls /s >"C:\Temp\xls.txt"` at the cmd prompt. It will give you a total file count at the bottom, as well as in each directory, and the space being used.

Comment: nice solution! here is an improved version: dir *.xls *.xlsx /s >"C:\Temp\xls.txt" (this command can include both xls & xlsx, but exclude *.xls.lnk, *.xlsx.lnk, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Install the wonderful [Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/), call it up and let it search the disk for a few minutes.

Then all you need to do is type `*.xls*` (for xls and xlsx), to instantly get their count.

Comment: file extension of Excel files is 'xls' & 'xlsx'